# plotting xts objects - passsing values for lwd and col parameters creating errors

Tags: r, plot, xts

Whenever I try to plot my xts object with values passed for parameter col and lwd, it returns an error saying that the parameter col (and then lwd if I comment out col) matched multiple values. Here is what the function looks like -

data is an xts object

```
plot(data, lwd=2, col="red")
```

Installing xtsExtra seems to solve the problem, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xts:::plot.xts` specifies several parameters when constructing the axes (`col`, `lwd`, `las`, and `mgp`), but it also passes `...` to the `axis` call. For example:

```
axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", ...)
```

`col` is already specified, so if you specify it also, it gets passed to `axis` via `...` and now there are two `col` arguments specified to the `axis` call.

This isn't a problem with `xtsExtra:::plot.xts` because those parameters are removed from `...` before `...` is passed to the `axis` call.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this to pass `type='n'` and then call `lines`:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols('CPIAUCSL',src='FRED')
xts::plot.xts(CPIAUCSL, type='n')
lines(CPIAUCSL, lwd=3, col='darkgoldenrod')
```

This does not require the `xtsExtra` package, which makes other changes to the plot and is (maybe) not being actively maintained. (At least it doesn't install via the package manager, today, on R 3.1.1.)