# How to set the "lwd" parameter in plot.xts?

Tags: r, plot, xts

I just want to set the line width of the line I'm plotting to be of a certain value. The rest (gridlines, border around graph) should remain 1.0 of width.

But if I set `par(lwd=2)` all lines are wider. If I set `plot.xts(AAPL,lwd=2)`, I get an error:

```
Error in axis(1, at = xycoords$x[ep], labels = names(ep), las = 1, lwd = 1,  : 
  formal argument "lwd" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Heres my code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
par(lwd=2)
plot.xts(AAPL)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [plotting xts objects - passsing values for lwd and col parameters creating errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473411/plotting-xts-objects-passsing-values-for-lwd-and-col-parameters-creating-error)

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this to pass `type='n'` and then call `lines`:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols('CPIAUCSL',src='FRED')
xts::plot.xts(CPIAUCSL, type='n')
lines(CPIAUCSL, lwd=3, col='darkgoldenrod')
```

This does not require the `xtsExtra` package, which makes other changes and is (maybe) not being actively maintained. (At least it doesn't install via the package manager, today, on R 3.1.1.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `xtsExtra` from R-Forge. It has lot of enhancement for plotting xts objects.

```
install.packages("xtsExtra", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

You can use

```
library(xtsExtra)

getSymbols("AAPL")

plot.xts(AAPL[,4], lwd = 2)
```

That will give you

[image]

Comment: `xtsExtra` may not be a workable solution indefinitely going forward, although the OP's problem still occurs (at least for me) with regular `xts::plot.xts`.